# Android: Using Cookies in HTTP Post request

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

I'm having some issues with getting myself authenticated with my server.

It works when I manually try to set cookies through a Google plugin like Postman but does not work when it is done through an android device or emulator.

Here is my code for that portion:

```
String url = "www.thisismyendpoint.com";
String ci_session = "ci_session=token";

CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
BasicClientCookie stdCookie = new BasicClientCookie("Cookie",ci_session);
cookieStore.addCookie(stdCookie);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE,
        cookieStore);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost, localContext);
```

This is my response in the logcat:

```
02-19 16:43:47.149: D/response(27539): response: <div style="border:1px solid             #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
02-19 16:43:47.149: D/response(27539): <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
02-19 16:43:47.149: D/response(27539): <p>Severity: Notice</p>
02-19 16:43:47.149: D/response(27539): <p>Message: Undefined index: ci_session</p>
02-19 16:43:47.149: D/response(27539): <p>Filename: controllers/test.php</p>
02-19 16:43:47.149: D/response(27539): <p>Line Number: 28</p>
02-19 16:43:47.149: D/response(27539): </div>
```

Am i doing something wrong? I've tried to set the ci_session into the headers as well but similarly it did not work. Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the PHP script has the problem. The message indicates that the "ci_session" not exists in the array that you use to capture the "ci_session" param sended from Java

Comment: but it works when i simulate the same request on the browser so i'm wondering if i failed to do something in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the cookie is set correctly?
In my case, I use HttpGet and set the cookie manually:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
```

The cookie is stored in the sharedPreferences. Should work for HttpPost the same way i think.

Comment: Yes i got it to work. Can't believe it. the simplest of solutions elude us all the time..

Comment: can you please post your whole solution

Comment: What do you need to understand? `httpGet` is a newly initialied Object, `cookie` is a string you save at a secure location. To call the website with the url (also a string), you have to call `new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet)`, but this is too offtopic in my eyes.

Comment: What if there's more than 1 cookie? @PhilippKuntschik

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problems. You should not create a new `DefaultHttpClient` for each new request. Instead, use a static singleton one and use it for all your Http Request needs.